# How to Convert a Circle (vtkActor) into Point Cloud Data vtkPoint

Tags: c#, vtk, point-clouds

I'm currently new to VTK, and i'm trying to generate a circle of point cloud data to add to a scanned model (which is also point cloud). I have the center point, normal vector, and radius. But I just need a way to generate the circle.

I've only looked into generating a normal circle. But looking into the VTK documentation I can't find anything related to converting vtkActor to pointcloud, only the other way around. (such as point cloud to surface etc).

```
// Creating a new circle Variables (these are declared in the class)
private Point3D centrePoint;
private UnitVector3D centreAxis;
private double radius;
Circle3D alignmentCircle; 

// In another function centrePoint, centreAxis, and radius are set

// Creating a new Circle in another function
alignmentCircle = new Circle3D(centrePoint, centreAxis, radius);                     scanEndPointCircleActor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(VtkElements.CreateCircle(alignmentCircle));

// I'm looking to try and convert the circle to a set of point cloud data around here. 

renderWindow.Render();
```

Currently what this does is generate a circle that is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`actor.GetMapper().GetInput().GetPoints()`

returns a `vtkPoints` object.